# MySQL Error #1241

Tags: mysql, subquery

this is my SQL:

```
UPDATE seg_guidesdata 
SET cash_box=(cash_box-(425,0)) 
WHERE idseg_guidesdata=(SELECT fk_guidedata FROM users WHERE idusers=180);
```

quite simple, but i get the error

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s).

I understand what the error means, but i dont know why i get it here. The subquery actually return 1 row with 1 column. I checked it:

PHPMyAdmin return of subquery:

[image]

So, anybody has an idea why i get this error?

THX

Comment: I solved it, the Problem was not the subquery, it was in the first part: 425,0 should be 425.0 :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal separator for a literal in an SQL query is the dot (`.`), regardless of any locale or formatting settings. Therefore you must represent the number 425,0 as `425.0`:

```
UPDATE ... SET cash_box=(cash_box-(425.0)) WHERE ...
```

---

The error message is coming from the comma being interpreted as a column separator, which makes `(425,0)` look like it is two columns.